# Understanding Reward Function $R:\mathbb{R}^6 \to \mathbb{R}$ by Visualizing

Tags: optimization, lie-groups, lie-algebras, machine-learning

I have a reward function $R:\mathbb{R}^6 \to \mathbb{R}$ and I can maximize it using the gradient ascent method. Any suggestion on how to visualize $R$ so that I can get some insight regarding its shape?

One obvious way is isolating the coordinates and generating separate plots but would this help to get an understanding of its overall shape?

As a side note, $R(\xi)$ is in fact cross-correlation between two continuous functions $f_1,f_2:\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ and $\xi \in \mathfrak{se}(3)$ is an element of a Lie algebra acting on $\mathbb{R}^3$. Hence, $\xi$ is the decision variable of optimization.

Comment: A $7$-dimensional graph... That's an interesting question, here's something I've just found on YouTube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wvsE8jm1GzE which utilizes AI to group points close to each other. Although this seems to work better with discrete subspace.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be a good idea for discrete space (multi-class classification in machine learning). Very nice video, thanks for sharing it. It reminded me of this work: http://papers.nips.cc/paper/2540-gaussian-process-latent-variable-models-for-visualisation-of-high-dimensional-data.pdf